# Calculating variance using kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

Want to calculate variance for a time series data of multiple restaurants with number of customers visting every day.

```
date          name       numCustomers
1-Sep-2016  restaurant1 40
2-Sep-2016  restaurant1 30
3-Sep-2016  restaurant1 35
--------------------------
1-Sep-2016  restaurant2 20
2-Sep-2016  restaurant2 24
--------------------------
1-Sep-2016  restaurant3 50
3-Sep-2016  restaurant3 45
```

For a each week, want to find variance in number of customers visiting each restaurant.

i.e. want to first bucketize the data per week. Then sum numCustomers for each restaurant and find variance on calculated sum. For above example need to find variance for [ restaurant1(40+30+35), restaurant2(20+24), restaurant3(50+45) ]

Looked at [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-extendedstats-aggregation.html) but not sure how this can be utilized here.

Comment: Is this a programming question? If so, include some code to indicate what you've tried, and how it goes wrong. If not, it's off topic and may be suited for [sf].

Comment: This is not a programming question, it is specific to Kibana

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.